# Accessing stored procedures from views on Firebird 2.1

Tags: stored-procedures, view, firebird, firebird2.1

I've this query for view:

```
SELECT BATCH, BS.FIELD1, BS.FIELD2 
from BATCHES 
left join P_BATCH_SUMMARY(BATCH) BS on 1=1
```

It works fine with Firebird 2.5, but not not on Firebird 2.1. Is it possible to circumvent this limitation with FB2.1?

Comment: What error do you get in 2.1?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel: Dynamic SQL Error feature is not uspported.

Comment: Looks like it is [new in 2.5](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/release_notes/html/rlsnotes252.html#rnfb25-ddl-createview). You could try to use a subselect (`... LEFT JOIN (SELECT ... FROM P_BATCH_SUMMARY(BATCH)) ...`), not sure if that would work though.

Comment: That doesn't work, it doesn't recognize column BATCH.

Comment: Then I guess you have no other option than to 1) upgrade to 2.5, or 2) replace usages of this view with a separate stored procedure or 3) replace usages of this view with the query itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the fact that referencing selectable stored procedures inside views was [introduced in Firebird 2.5](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/release_notes/html/en/2_5/rnfb25-ddl.html#rnfb25-ddl-createview) the only options you have are:

1. Upgrade to Firebird 2.5
2. Replace this view with an equivalent selectable stored procedure
3. Replace usages of this view with the query itself